# Using a Provider in a Custom Class - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement some custom classes in my Ionic 3 project to help handle data in a proper OOP fashion. However, I am think what I am trying to achieve is actually an anti-pattern to Angular and Ionic design patterns.

For each user, I want to make a user object. I have a provider named `provider` that performs some http call. Each user object will be able to use a method that makes `provider`'s http call.

This works fine if I pass `Provider` through the constructor like so:

```
export class User {

    //...various user attributes....

    constructor(payload, public provider: Provider){
        this.provider.doSomethingHttp(payload).subscribe(val => {
        // do something with response
        })
    }
}
```

It does not work if I do something like this:

```
export class User {

    //...various user attributes....
    public provider: Provider;

    constructor(payload){
        this.provider.doSomethingHttp(payload).subscribe(val => {
        // do something with response
        })
    }
}
```

provider is now `undefined`.

Why is this the case? Must a provider be passed through a constructor?

Also, if I instantiate a new class of `User` somewhere, I will have to pass in arguments for the providers, which doesn't work either.

```
let user = new User(payload, this.provider)
```

Obviously, seems like there is some better way to handle this. Perhaps it is better to not have a bunch of objects floating around that make there own http calls.

Answer (score 1):

The providers are created by **Dependency Injection**, and to have the instances of them you have to add them in the constructors of your components like your first example and add it to app module providers.

I have never seen the providers in other classes than components and providers, I think that in the place that you are creating the user (I supose is a component or a provider) you can add the provider in the constructor, and if needed, pass it to the `User` constructor.

Other option is to remove the provider from the `User class`, create a new provider (lets call it **UserPrivider**) which will have the first `provider` added in the constructor, and in this new **UserProvider**, implement a method that creates the user and after the creation makes the call to the first provider, in order that every time you need to create an User, you inject the UserProvider and call this method.

Answer (score 0):

> "Why is this the case?"

provider is `undefined` because it is never assigned.

```
export class User {
    constructor(payload, public provider: Provider) { }
}
```

is shorthand for

```
export class User {
    public provider: Provider;
    constructor(payload, provider: Provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
}
```

> "Must a provider be passed through a constructor?"

That is one way but `this.provider =` must happen some way, at lest.

> "Obviously, seems like there is some better way to handle this. Perhaps it is better to not have a bunch of objects floating around that make there own http calls."

Like @Octavio Garbarino said typically you'd have a service that makes the http call and returns the `User` instance in say a `getUser(payload): User` method.